# Semisimple module implies free module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know free modules aren't always semisimple($\mathbb{Z}$ module over $\mathbb{Z}$ for example), but the converse seems to be true? My proof:

Let $U=S_1\bigoplus...\bigoplus S_n$ be a semisimple module over a ring, and $S_1,...,S_n$ simple submodules of $U$, and let $s_i$ be a non zero element of $S_i$ for each $i$. Each $u\in U$ can be written as a sum of elements of each $S_i$, and these are simple modules so each element is a scalar multiple of $s_i$. The set $\{s_1,...,s_n\}$ is linearly independent (sum is direct) and generates $U$, so it's a basis.

If this proof is correct, then how come $\mathbb{Z_p}$ (p prime) as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module is simple (implies semisimple) but not free?

Comment: When you know a counterexample, a good way to find the error is to go through your proof line by line with the counterexample and find the first statement that is false in that example.

Comment: What's the simplest semisimple ring you know that is not a division algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The set $\{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}$ is linearly independent

This is incorrect in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, as $p \cdot 1 = 0$.